# scikit-learn - Process input as DataFrame in custom estimator

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'd like to write my own scikit-learn estimator by extending `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`. In this estimator, I'd like to use Pandas dataframe operations (like grouping). So far, I have this basic skeleton:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class GroupSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, group_column):
        self.group_column = group_column

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print(type(X))
        return self
```

Then I run this as the following (with `X` and `y` being pandas dataframes):

```
GroupSelector("agroup").fit(X,y)
```

However, the print call in `fit` says that the output is a numpy array. In my `fit` method, I'd like to use the different grouping operators on dataframes.

Is there a reason by scikit-learn converts the inputs to numpy arrays? How can I keep them as dataframes?

Comment: Are you sure your X is a not a numpy array ? Because I tried what you've done and i get a pandas dataframe

Comment: @MMF, Hmm, weird, I updated `scikit-learn` and I got the expected results.. Thanks for checking it!